# i want to add my gallery to facebook from the localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on photo sharing web site and i want to add functionality which can create my application's whole gallery in to the face book gallaries . Is ther any code whch can be added to do such things .
Please help me out . IF find any link, kindly share in the answer , i hope i am clear anough ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook supports several APIs (RESTful, Javascript, etc. plus wrappers for many languages) that will allow you to create galleries and upload pictures on behalf of a user.

See the [Facebook Developer's wiki](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com.) for more details:

Learn about the API, especially the photo part. That should get you started. I suspect you are not going to get anyone on StackOverflow willing to write all your code for you, but if you have a more specific question they may answer that.

Answer (score 1):

You also might want to look at the two popular facebook plugin for rails , namely :rfacebook and facebooker .

Comment: thanks but i got the answer and i know about all the plugings friend. have u worked ? if yes can u help in detail , if no thanks .